# How can I enclose a mysql::Conn in a lazy_static macro?

Tags: mysql, rust

This code:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;
extern crate mysql;

use mysql::*;

fn some_fn() {
    lazy_static! {
        static ref CONNECTION: Conn = Conn::new("mysql://root:password@127.0.0.1:3306/mydb?prefer_socket=false").unwrap();
    }
}
```

generates a very long error message:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `*mut std::os::raw::c_void: std::marker::Sync` is not satisfied in `winapi::minwinbase::OVERLAPPED`
  --> src\main.rs:8:5
   |
8  | /     lazy_static! {
9  | |         static ref CONNECTION: Conn = Conn::new("mysql://root:password@127.0.0.1:3306/mydb?prefer_socket=false").unwrap();
10 | |     }
   | |_____^ `*mut std::os::raw::c_void` cannot be shared between threads safely
   |
   = help: within `winapi::minwinbase::OVERLAPPED`, the trait `std::marker::Sync` is not implemented for `*mut std::os::raw::c_void`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `winapi::minwinbase::OVERLAPPED`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Sync` for `std::ptr::Unique<winapi::minwinbase::OVERLAPPED>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::boxed::Box<winapi::minwinbase::OVERLAPPED>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `named_pipe::Overlapped`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `named_pipe::PipeClient`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::option::Option<named_pipe::PipeClient>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::io::BufWriter<named_pipe::PipeClient>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::option::Option<std::io::BufWriter<named_pipe::PipeClient>>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `bufstream::InternalBufWriter<named_pipe::PipeClient>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::io::BufReader<bufstream::InternalBufWriter<named_pipe::PipeClient>>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `bufstream::BufStream<named_pipe::PipeClient>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `mysql::io::Stream`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::option::Option<mysql::io::Stream>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `mysql::Conn`
   = note: required by `lazy_static::lazy::Lazy`
   = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate (in Nightly builds, run with -Z external-macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Is it because `mysql::Conn` is not intended to use in multithreaded apps?
How I can use lazy_static if my program is not multithreaded and I use non-thread-safe types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works just fine... on macOS. I believe this to be [a bug with the 
implementation of the MySQL crate](https://github.com/blackbeam/rust-mysql-simple/issues/135), and the author agreed, fixing the bug in less than a day. You should be able to just upgrade the crate and use your original code.

---

As a temporary workaround, you can wrap the `Conn` in a `Mutex`:

```
use mysql::*;
use std::sync::Mutex;

fn some_fn() {
    lazy_static! {
        static ref CONNECTION: Mutex<Conn> = Mutex::new(Conn::new("mysql://root:password@127.0.0.1:3306/mydb?prefer_socket=false").unwrap());
    }
}
```

> if my program is not multithreaded and I use non-thread-safe types?

I *always* recommend against using global variables, threads or not. Instead, create your `Conn` at the top of your program and pass references to it into all of your functions.